# Using a binary counter with ic sram

Tags: counter, binary, sram

I am using the as6c62256 ic sram, this is the datasheet: [datasheet](https://www.alliancememory.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/AS6C62256.pdf)

I am trying to write 1000 words of 8 bit, and then read them from the sram

is it possible to connect a binary counter to the adress pins of this ic to read and write data?

Write mode: counter begin from 0, for every adress write a word, increment counter and the next word and so on, etc...

Reset counter to 0 to Begin Reading

Read mode: increment counter, read data the corresponding Word

Help is appreciated, thanks to all of you

Comment: The only question in your question is "is it possible to connect a binary counter to the adress pins of this ic to read and write data?" - to which the answer is simply "yes". Would you like to clarify what you're really asking and where you're getting stuck?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i am newbie, and i am confused because in the dartasheet, and in other video i saw they use a decoder and not a binary counter, that's why i was wondering and i asked it

Comment: The only decoder mentioned in the datasheet is the address decoder *inside the IC*. Everything in the "FUNCTIONAL BLOCK DIAGRAM" is inside the IC, not parts you add to make it work.

Comment: Good, thank you for the clarification, ans please make your comment an answer so i mark it as an answer